# Constructor dependency injection with Servlet 3.0?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection

Since Servlet 3.0 it is possible to register Servlet instances programmatically with `javax.servlet.ServletContext#addServlet`. This class has also a `createServlet` method which analyses some annotations and performs dependency injection. I wonder if I need this method if I don't need the annotation processing. I'd like to have a servlet with a usual constructor to set required dependencies via dependency injection.

```
@Inject
public MyServlet(SomeDependency sd) {  // Constructor
  ...
}
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to construct a servlet instance "by hand" without `createServlet`? (`new MyServlet()`)
- Is it possible to use the dependency injection mechanism of a Java EE server to perform constructor injection? How to do it? Or is a separate DI framework like Guice required?

Answer (score 5):

The recent Java EE 6 standard now supports dependency injection for servlets, the relevant part is called JSR-299 or CDI. The JSR-299 reference implementation, [JBoss weld](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/), can be deployed into servlet containers like Tomcat or Jetty as well if you don't want to use a full Java EE 6 application server like glassfish v3 e.g.

By the way, with an embedded Jetty server you can use its custom API to add preconfigured servlet instances.

Comment: Thanks, JSR-299 is what i'm looking for. The Weld documentation says: "We may obtain an instance of TextTranslator by injecting it into a constructor, method or field of a bean, or a field or method of a Java EE component class such as a servlet." http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/intro.html It seems like constructor injection is not possible with servlets.

Comment: Note that early versions of Weld were rather ... unhelpful if you did not get the configuration 100% correct.  This may have improved since.

Answer (score 2):

Guice does this out of the box without the need for Java EE servers.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

Comment: Guice adds a layer above servlets. That was useful before Java EE 6. Today dependency injection is part of Java EE and I would prefer to use it without an additional framework - if possible.