# How to use dependency injection in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection

How to inject an object to a servlet?

I mean, that I cannot use a constructor DI because servlets are instantiated by a servlets container. 
And I also don't see a nice way of implementing setter-based DI for a servlet.

Should I use servlet listener? Are there any best-practices?

P.S. I don't have neither Spring nor Guice nor any other DI framework, I'm interested in manual dependency injection.

Comment: Look at this question. Maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1992132/891391

Answer (score 24):

This is possible under Servlet 3.0. You register a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which programmatically registers Servlet instances with the [addServlet(String, Servlet)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet%28java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.Servlet%29) method of ServletContext just before the app starts. Since you're instantiating the Servlet instances yourself, you can give them proper constructors and inject dependencies.

I created [an example](https://github.com/seanjreilly/httpServletExample) a while ago that illustrates the basic technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume services which are created/managed by some IOC container (Spring, Guice)

You could create a ContextAware implementation and Pull out the beans as and when needed from Servlet

Comment: Using Spring this way is not Dependency Injection, but instead is effectively using a Service Locator, [which is considered an antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JNDI, the Java Naming and Directory Interface, and `@Resource` to inject it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't JNDI an implementation of Service Locator, not Dependency Injection, and therefore subject to the usual criticisms of [Service Locator as an antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)?